# Unable to create a new remote session. (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)"}

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, katalon-studio, apple-developer

automatically my macOS upgrade to the macOS ventura (latest version). of course my xcode (now 14.x) was upgrade too. i use katalon to run mobile ios testing. before, i already make ios mobile project in katalon using the version of macOS before ventura.
But after i ugrade i did not run my test suite in katalon and i got this error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install '/var/folders/41/yf384h9j5vz6nd_sjztz_xgw0000gn/T/Katalon/Appium/Temp1694961965567/2023817-3873-od3ik2.6936m/Runner.app':
  - Unexpected data: {"Error":"ApplicationVerificationFailed","ErrorDetail":-402620395,"ErrorDescription":"Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OfnClX/extracted/Runner.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)"}
  - 'ios-deploy' utility has not been found in PATH. Is it installed?
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MIIs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:f2:f6dc:d99f:65cf%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5.2', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install '/var/folders/41/yf384h9j5vz6nd_sjztz_xgw0000gn/T/Katalon/Appium/Temp1694961965567/2023817-3873-od3ik2.6936m/Runner.app':
  - Unexpected data: {"Error":"ApplicationVerificationFailed","ErrorDetail":-402620395,"ErrorDescription":"Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OfnClX/extracted/Runner.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)"}
  - 'ios-deploy' utility has not been found in PATH. Is it installed?
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MIIs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:f2:f6dc:d99f:65cf%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5.2', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.components.impl.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.runAndWait(ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.java:49)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.mobile.objectspy.components.MobileLocalAppComposite$12.run(MobileLocalAppComposite.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install '/var/folders/41/yf384h9j5vz6nd_sjztz_xgw0000gn/T/Katalon/Appium/Temp1694961965567/2023817-3873-od3ik2.6936m/Runner.app':
  - Unexpected data: {"Error":"ApplicationVerificationFailed","ErrorDetail":-402620395,"ErrorDescription":"Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OfnClX/extracted/Runner.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)"}
  - 'ios-deploy' utility has not been found in PATH. Is it installed?
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MIIs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:f2:f6dc:d99f:65cf%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5.2', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install '/var/folders/41/yf384h9j5vz6nd_sjztz_xgw…
```

please help me. thank you

i already regist my team and my device to apple developer.com
i expect i can run my test suite with macOS venture (the latest version of macOS)